# How to use const which declared in one file in another file?

Tags: reactjs, components, tailwind-css

I have different components in which I must use const that created in other file in another file.

So I have **filter_price.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import products from '../../product.json'

import ReactSlider from 'react-slider'

const MIN = 758;
const MAX = 110110;


function Filter_Price() {
  const [priceRangeValue, setPriceRangeValue] = useState([MIN, MAX]);
  const filteredProducts = products.filter((product) => 
    ((priceRangeValue[0] === '' || product.price >= parseFloat(priceRangeValue[0])) & 
     (priceRangeValue[1] === '' || product.price <= parseFloat(priceRangeValue[1]))))

  return (
        <div>
          <div className='w-[95%] h-[2px] mx-[2.5%] opacity-70 bg-white rounded-md'/>
          <div className='mb-8'>
            <h1 className='font-gilroyMedium text-base text-white pt-6 pl-6'>Ціна</h1>
            <div className='flex flex-row gap-8 justify-center pt-6 pb-8'>
              <label className='flex flex-row items-center text-white gap-3'>
                Від 
                <input 
                  type="number"
                  name="minValue" 
                  value={priceRangeValue[0]}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setPriceRangeValue([Number(e.target.value), priceRangeValue[1]]);
                  }}
                  className='w-24 h-12 rounded appearance-none bg-[#121212] border border-white outline-none'/>
              </label>
              
              <label className='flex flex-row items-center text-white gap-3'>
                <input 
                  type="number"
                  name="maxValue" 
                  value={priceRangeValue[1]}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setPriceRangeValue([priceRangeValue[0], Number(e.target.value)]);
                  }}
                  className='w-24 h-12 rounded appearance-none bg-[#121212] border border-white outline-none'></input> 
                    До
              </label>
            </div>

            {/* npm i react-slider@2.0.6 */}
            <ReactSlider
              id="slider"
              className="horizontal-slider w-1/2 h-5 mx-auto"
              thumbClassName="w-5 h-5 bg-[#d9d9d9] rounded-full text-white"
              trackClassName="h-2.5 bg-[#7d7d7d] my-[5px] rounded"
              min={MIN}
              max={MAX}
              value={priceRangeValue}
              onChange={setPriceRangeValue}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Filter_Price;
```

and **catalog.js**

```
import quick_buy_btn from "../img/btn-quick-buy.png";
import products from '../product.json'


function Catalog() {

  return (
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-10 pb-24 
                tablet:grid-cols-3 tablet:gap-x-12 tablet:gap-y-4 
                laptop:gap-x-16 laptop:gap-y-8 
                desktop:gap-x-16 desktop:gap-y-12">
          
          {products.slice(0, 12).map((product) => (
            <div key={product.id} className="group relative">
              <div className="aspect-h-1 aspect-w-1 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-md bg-[#F6F6F6] 
                    tapble:aspect-none">
                <img
                  src={product.color?.black?.available ? product.color?.black?.imageSrc1 : product.color?.white?.imageSrc1}
                  alt={product.color?.black?.available ? product.color?.black?.imageAlt : product.color?.white?.imageAlt}
                  className="h-full w-full object-contain object-center group-hover:opacity-75"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mt-4 flex justify-between">
                <div>
                  <h3 className="text-base font-gilroyRegular 
                        laptop:text-xl 
                        desktop:text-2xl">
                    <a href={product.href}>
                      <span aria-hidden="true" className="absolute inset-0" />
                      {product.name}
                    </a>
                  </h3>
                  <p className="mt-1 text-sm font-gilroyRegular text-gray-500 
                        laptop:text-lg 
                        desktop:text-xl">
                    {product.color?.black?.available ? `black` : `white`}
                  </p>
                </div>
                  {product.sale != null ?
                  <div>
                    <p className="text-base font-gilroyBold line-through text-[#767676] 
                          laptop:text-lg 
                          desktop:text-xl">
                      {product.price} ₴
                    </p>
                    <p className="text-base font-gilroyBold text-black 
                          laptop:text-lg 
                          desktop:text-xl">
                      {product.sale} ₴
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  :
                  <div>
                    <p className="text-base font-gilroyBold text-black 
                          laptop:text-lg 
                          desktop:text-xl">
                      {product.price} ₴
                    </p>
                    <p className="hidden">
                      {product.sale} ₴
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  }
              </div>
              <img  src={quick_buy_btn} 
                    className="w-[42px] h-[42px] mt-3 
                        tablet:w-8 tablet:h-8 
                        laptop:w-12 laptop:h-12"/>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>                
  );
}

export default Catalog;
```

I tried `const filteredProducts = products.filter((product) => ((priceRangeValue[0] === '' || product.price >= parseFloat(priceRangeValue[0])) & (priceRangeValue[1] === '' || product.price <= parseFloat(priceRangeValue[1]))))` declared in the top level and using `import { filteredProducts } from "./Filter_Price.js"` but filter don't work because when I changed price range and closed filter menu after that opened filter menu again I saw the price didn't change in input field.

When I tried to use all this code in one file all works, but working with big file is uncomfortable. So I start separating to components. Help me please...